# Can't get the included view to align to the parent bottom in a layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to do a simple layout in android that includes another file which is a bottom navigation consisting of three buttons.

I can't get the included file to line up at the bottom.  Here is my xml for the layout (the TextView shows up aligned to parent bottom, but included file doesn't):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_background"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/patientDOBBlock"
    tools:text="Test Navigation Text"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
<include
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_below="@+id/patientDOBBlock"
    layout="@layout/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The included file:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/task_base_buttons"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="66dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTaskBack"
        style="@style/NeutrifProText.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="@string/action_back"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btnTaskContinue"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnTaskContinue" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTaskContinue"
        style="@style/NeutrifProText.Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_rect_color_primary"
        android:text="@string/action_continue"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnTaskSkip"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnTaskBack" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTaskSkip"
        style="@style/NeutrifProText.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="@string/action_skip"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btnTaskContinue"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnTaskContinue" />

 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
 </merge>
```

Any idea why?  BTW, this same included file shows up at the bottom in a fragment.

**EDIT**:  I'm including the layout of the fragment where the layout does appear at the bottom

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/task_constraint_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.rangerhealth.rangerprovider.view.fragment.BaseTaskFragment"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/task_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/title_font_size"
    tools:text="Title"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/task_subtitle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/task_title"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:text="Subtitle"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/task_title" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/task_description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="21dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    tools:text="Description"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/task_subtitle" />


<include layout="@layout/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/task_placeholder"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/task_description"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/task_base_buttons"
    >

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I had to add a LinearLayout, and then it all worked:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_background"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/patientDOBBlock"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/navigation"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:text="Test Navigation Text" />
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:id="@+id/navigation">

<include
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutNavigation"
    layout="@layout/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the layout you have the included layout aligned to the parent bottom and below `patientDOBBlock`. These two directives are in conflict. I assume that you want the bottom navigation and the text view to both be aligned to the parent bottom and overlapped.

In the layout with the include remove the following line:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/patientDOBBlock"
```

That leaves the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/activity_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/patientDOBBlock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        tools:text="Test Navigation Text" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        layout="@layout/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In bottom_navigation.xml, remove the `merge` tags. From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Merge):

> The  tag helps eliminate redundant view groups in your view hierarchy when including one layout within another.

Since you need to keep the `ConstraintLayout` in the included file, you don't have redundant view groups, so you don't need the merge tag. The use of the merge tag also prevents the application of the layout parameters to the include file. See [this](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Include).

> You can also override all the layout parameters (any android:layout_* attributes) of the included layout's root view by specifying them in the  tag.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/task_base_buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTaskBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="action_back"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btnTaskContinue"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnTaskContinue" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTaskContinue"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="action_continue"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnTaskSkip"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnTaskBack" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTaskSkip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="action_skip"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btnTaskContinue"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnTaskContinue" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Although it is not hurting anything, the constraints specified in the `ConstraintLayout` will have no effect unless the parent is also a `ConstraintLayout`, so they can just be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Change your XML with the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/patientDOBBlock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/navigation"
        android:gravity="center"
        tools:text="Test Navigation Text" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        layout="@layout/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

bottom_navigation.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/task_base_buttons"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="66dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTaskBack"
        style="@style/NeutrifProText.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="@string/action_back"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btnTaskContinue"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnTaskContinue" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTaskContinue"
        style="@style/NeutrifProText.Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_rect_color_primary"
        android:text="@string/action_continue"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnTaskSkip"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnTaskBack" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTaskSkip"
        style="@style/NeutrifProText.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="@string/action_skip"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btnTaskContinue"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnTaskContinue" />

 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I hope it will work for you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_background"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
>
<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/patientDOBBlock"
tools:text="Test Navigation Text"
android:layout_above = "@+id/navigation"/>

<include
android:id="@id/navigation"
android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
layout="@layout/bottom_navigation"
android:layout_height="66dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This should work perfectly